# Autenticação JWT com role claims em ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, jwt

> **RESOLVIDO - Authorize com roles**
>
> Com ajuda deste link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025009/10647645
>
> E uma resposta no post com os arquivos final com a resolução
>
> **NÃO RESOLVIDO** - IdentityServer, como fazer e usar?

Tenho 3 problemas iniciais aqui:

1. Decodificar do token: quando receber a requisição, preciso decodificar o token para fazer a validação e permitir acessar as roles com o authorize.
2. Authorize com roles no meu sistema: colocando uma politica eu consegui fazer, mas com as roles nao consegui.
3. Soluções separadas: tenho a solução do Identity e do sistema em si, portanto, preciso saber como fazer para o "sistema em si visualizar" o Identity para que faça a validação do token e assim, fazendo a autorização do mesmo.

---

**ARQUIVOS**

appsettings.json

```
"JwtKey": "MYSECRET",
"JwtIssuer": "http://localhost:8040/",
"JwtExpireDays": 30,
```

Startup.cs

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]);
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

// Usando a politica
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth.AddPolicy("BearerPolicy", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()           
      .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
});
```

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<AccountModel> Login([FromBody] AccountModel model)
{
    var usuario = new ApplicationUser();
    ...
    var appUser = _userManager.Users.Include(...);

    var claims = await GetValidClaims(appUser);
    var accountModel = new AccountModel(usuario, _roleManager);
    accountModel.Token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser, claims);

    return accountModel;
}

private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]);

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),

        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
    };
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    claims.AddRange(userClaims);
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
        if (role != null)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
    }
    return claims;
}
```

RoleModel

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NomeNormalizado { get; set; }
    public string SeloConcorrencia { get; set; }

    public RoleModel() { }

    public RoleModel(ApplicationRole applicationRole)
    {
        Id = applicationRole.Id;
        Nome = applicationRole.Name;
        NomeNormalizado = applicationRole.NormalizedName;
        SeloConcorrencia = applicationRole.ConcurrencyStamp;
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string PrimeiroNome { get; set; }
    public string UltimoNome { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}
```

ApplicationRole

```
public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}
```

ApplicationUserRole

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Request POST Angular

```
AdicionarPessoa(pessoa: Pessoa): Observable<Pessoa> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Pessoa>(environment.url + "/Pessoa/AdicionarPessoa", pessoa, environment.token);
  };
```

Environment

```
token: { headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")}}
```

PessoaController

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Pessoa/AdicionarPessoa")]
// [Authorize("BearerPolicy")] <-- Usando a politica
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
public Pessoa AdicionarPessoa([FromBody]Pessoa model)
```

> ERRO: http://localhost/api/Pessoa/AdicionarPessoa 401 (Unauthorized)

**EDIÇÕES**

Eu fiz o exemplo em outro metodo, assim nao preciso passar um json no post:

Meu Token

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PRIMEIRA TENTATIVA - FALHA**

ObterTodosPessoa com Role Administrador

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Pessoa/ObterTodosPessoas")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
public IEnumerable<Pessoa> ObterTodosPessoas()
{
    var PessoaRepositoryVar = new PessoaRepository();
    var Pessoas = PessoaRepositoryVar.ObterTodos();
    return Pessoas;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Console POSTMAN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Fiz algumas modificações desde o dia que postei aqui, portanto estou editando o post para ficar o mais igual que tenho possivel.**

Durante algum tempo de pesquisa e estudo, me deparei com algumas duvidas:

No começo do post, falei que tinha 3 problemas iniciais, vou responde-los e gostaria que voces falassem "é isso, esta certo assim..." ou "não, esta errado, pense desta forma:....", agradeço desde ja!

1. Decodificar o token

   Não tem porque eu decodificar o token, ja que o authorize e authentication é feito no startup.cs
2. Authorize

   Consegui fazer, na resposta do post tem como eu fiz
3. Soluções separadas

   Não sei se ficou claro para todos, mas de grosso modo, eu preciso abrir 2 visual studio, 1 para carregar o Identity e outro para carregar a outra solução. E sobre o IdentityServer, eu procurei pouco sobre, quero conseguir fazer funcionar as roles no Identity para depois tentar fazer o IdentityServer e colocar no restante do sistema... Se alguem tiver algum material que explique isso, agradeço

---

**ARQUIVOS 07/08/2019**

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseOracle(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultUI()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddCors();

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]);
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        };
    });
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task<AccountModel> Login([FromBody] AccountModel model)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var usuario = new ApplicationUser();
        var signInResultado = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult();


        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
             usuario = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        }).Wait();

            ... 

        if (signInResultado.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == usuario.Id);

            var claims = await GetValidClaims(appUser);
            var accountModel = new AccountModel(usuario, _roleManager);

            accountModel.Token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser, claims);
            return accountModel;
        }

    }
    return model;
}
private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]);

    // AQUI TENHO 2 FORMAS DE FAZER, NÃO SEI QUAL FUNCIONA OU QUAL A MAIS CORRETA
    // FORMA 1
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),

        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    // FORMA 2
    var tokens = new JwtSecurityToken(
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokens);

}
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
    };
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    claims.AddRange(userClaims);
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
        if (role != null)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
    }
    return claims;
}
```

Os outros arquivos permanecem os mesmos...

Minha maior dificuldade no momento é conseguir fazer o C# identificar/validar/autorizar as roles que tem no token passado pelo header!

Comment: Amigo, coloca também o seu request no POST para que possamos ver como você o está fazendo, pode ser algo nele.

Comment: @MayconF.Castro, nao sei se coloquei o q falou

Comment: Amigo você tem que passar o seu token no header da sua requisição, pelo que estou vendo, você está apenas disparando a url por isso está retornando 401 - unauthorized. Tenta adicionar o seu token no header da sua requisição e me fala se deu certo.

Comment: Voce pode me ajudar com isso? Nao sei como coloco uma informação no header da requisição

Comment: Amigo dá uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286764/angular-httpclient-doesnt-send-header 
Ele ensina como adicionar header nessa sua requisição, não posso ajudar muito pq nunca trabalhei com angular ;-)
Espero que te ajude, depois fala se deu certo

Comment: No seu caso o header deve ser, Authorization  e o seu token de acesso

Comment: Fiz a requisação pelo postman, editei o post, deu 401 Unauthorized

Comment: eu adicionei uma `policy` e fiz com o `Authorize("Policy")`, funcionou dentro do Identity, porem as outras soluções que estao separadas, nao funciona. Mas nao é só isso, eu gostaria de fazer pelo roles tambem: exemplo: `Authorize(Roles = "Adm")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou postar por aqui, como ficaram os arquivos com a resolução para Authorize com as roles. Importante: Não fiz com o IdentityServer ainda.

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>

        options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
              .AddDefaultUI()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddCors();

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        var symetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]));
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = symetricSecurityKey

                };
            });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(c =>
        {
            c.AllowAnyOrigin();
            c.AllowAnyMethod();
            c.AllowAnyHeader();
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var tokenStr = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();

                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = handler.ReadToken(tokenStr) as JwtSecurityToken;
                var nameid = token.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type.Contains("nameidentifier")).Value;

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims);
                context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            }
            await next();
        });
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<AccountModel> Login([FromBody] AccountModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var usuario = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(usuario, model.Senha);

        var signInResultado = await _signInManager
            .PasswordSignInAsync(
                usuario.UserName,
                model.Senha,
                isPersistent: false,
                lockoutOnFailure: false
            );

        if (signInResultado.Succeeded)
        {
            var appUser = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == usuario.Id);
            var claims = await GetValidClaims(appUser);

            var accountModel = new AccountModel(usuario, _roleManager);
            accountModel.Token = GenerateJwtToken(appUser, claims);
            return accountModel;
        }
    }
    return model;
}

private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user, List<Claim> claims)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtKey"]);

    var tokens = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
        audience: _configuration["JwtIssuer"],
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JwtExpireDays"])),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokens);

}

private async Task<List<Claim>> GetValidClaims(ApplicationUser user)
{
    IdentityOptions _options = new IdentityOptions();
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(_options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, user.UserName)
    };
    var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    claims.AddRange(userClaims);
    foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
        if (role != null)
        {
            var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);
            foreach (Claim roleClaim in roleClaims)
            {
                claims.Add(roleClaim);
            }
        }
    }
    return claims;
}
```

Authorize

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<RoleModel>> Get()
```

Request Header Angular

```
getAll(): Observable<...[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<...[]>(environment.url + "api",
    { headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token });
}
```